# What does Internet Explorer do to notify other browsers about proxy settings change?

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, proxy

I've come to a strange behaviour, if I change proxy settings on Windows 7 in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Google Chrome acts like nothing happened - even after restarting it. However when I start/restart Internet Explorer, somehow it "tells" Chrome about the changes and suddenly Chrome starts to use the proxy settings - even without restarting Chrome.

What does Internet Explorer "do" so Chrome notices that?

Is something similar, something that IE Explorer do, achieveable in C++ ?

*PS: `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` does not seem to be the thing...*

Comment: Probably a broadcast window message.  No idea which one though.  I suppose you could write a program to listen for broadcast messages, and see which one the Internet control panel is generating.  Or it might be documented somewhere.

Comment: Could you serve an example of catching an analyzing messages like these ? :) thakns

Comment: I'd be inclined to change the proxy settings via the offical Windows API, rather than poking around in the registry directly.  All applications should then be able to pick it up correctly.
This KB explains how - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226473

Comment: Changing the registry values is not supposed to trigger any behaviour, either strange or normal. All the behaviour you can rely on after changing registry values of other programs is the undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must send broadcast message [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

upd.
Parameters must be set to null like this:
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_SETTINGCHANGE,(WPARAM)(0),(LPARAM)(0));

Or you can use [InternetSetOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fuction from WinInet library like this:
InternetSetOption(NULL,INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED,NULL,0);

Comment: Could please specify some example of how this message should be formatted for proxy settings change? Thank you :)

Comment: @javeweb have you ever used spy++?  I'd start by spying on chrome and seeing what parameters of that message show up myself.

Comment: You better use `InternetSetOption()` or any other official API for changing system settings. Changing the registry values directly is not supposed to trigger any reaction from any running program.

Comment: `INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED` is the ONLY way to notify of proxy settings change. WM_SETTINGCHANGE will have no effect.